# How to move a partition from /dev/kubuntu-vg to /dev/sdax

Tags: encryption, gparted, partitioning, luks

I want to install windows alongside my encrypted
kubuntu installation and I am having some issues.
What i tried doing was booting into a live usb, decrypting the encrypted drive and then shrinking /dev/kubuntu-vg/root (I could not shrink /dev/sda3(the luks encrypted partition) directly). This gave me the partition I wanted but now it's stuck inside /dev/kubuntu-vg and windows doesnt detect it because its inside an encrypted volume.
How can move the partition I made outside that volume group?

Screenshots of kubuntu-vg and the drive -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjB47.jpg

Comment: why are you doing things this way arround? (install kubuntu then windows) when everyone agrees it should be done in the oposite order? https://www.google.com/search?q=what+should+i+install+first+linux+or+windows&oq=which+should+I+install+first+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.8407j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @tatsu If UEFI the order is irrelevant. The problem here is much worse: Not understanding LVM and not understanding that unallocated space is not a partition.

Comment: @tatsu  I already had this linux installation for quite some time and I dont want to reinstall everything.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I know that unallocated space is not a partition, putting that free space in a partition changes nothing in my case. Also, I don't understand LVM but since I want to do just this one specific thing I don't want to invest too much time learning it.

Comment: But you have to understand that you need to use LVM tools to manage the volumes, in this case to shrink the whole volume after shrinking the partitions inside. And I'm not the one to teach you bacause I don't know myself other than the aforementiined theoretical principles.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I did try to shrink the volume group from the partition manager but everything is greyed out. I also tried looking around the wrb but the only things I found is how to reduce a logical volume, not a volume group.

Comment: My point exactly, you can't do that, you have to use LVM tools.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia do you know any commands i could use? I already tried vgreduce but it tells me that resize2fs(which works with lvreduce) isnt a known command.

Comment: Also already said I don't. Sorry.